# Powershell script ignoring filter

Tags: powershell, active-directory

I'm using the following one-liner to get a list of users who aren't disabled, and whose accounts expire, with some properties:

```
Get-ADUser -Filter {(Enabled -eq $true) -and (accountExpires -ne 0)} -Properties name, mail, c, physicalDeliveryOfficeName, telephoneNumber, manager, title, description | select-object name, mail, c, physicalDeliveryOfficeName, telephoneNumber, manager, title, description
```

It works, except it grabs everyone in my domain, not just the ones whose accounts expire as indicated.  Why is it ignoring the accountExpires portion of the script?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason for wrong result is your wrong assumption, that every not-expiring account has value 0 in `accountExpires` attribute. In my tests that applied only to Administrator.
Every other account had `[int64]::MaxValue` there - so you need to include this in your filter:

```
$Max = [int64]::MaxValue
Get-ADUser -Filter {
    (Enabled -eq $true) -and 
    (accountExpires -ne 0) -and 
    (accountExpires -ne $Max)
}
```

Comment: Thanks, except this grabs all of the accounts that do expire; the opposite of what I want.

Is there a way to reverse this?

Comment: Reversing it should be easy by reversing logic of the filter `...) -and ((acountExpires -eq 0) -or (accountExpires -eq $Max))`